# Unable to make ODBC connection on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql, odbc

I usually access an ODBC connection through a CentOS server, and I'm trying to make the same connection locally on my Ubuntu Trusty laptop. So far as I can tell I've duplicated everything properly across the two machines, but I just can't get it to work. I had it working on an old laptop on the same network, so I think I can rule out firewalls/routing/etc.

When I try to test the connection I get:

```
me@T420:~/tmp$ iodbctest
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0709.0909

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): ?

DSN                              | Driver                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NZSQL_SERVER                    | NetezzaSQL                              

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): NZSQL_SERVER
1: SQLDriverConnect = ������ (33) SQLSTATE=
1: ODBC_Connect = ������ (33) SQLSTATE=
```

my /etc/odbcinst.ini:

Have a nice day.patrickmc@patrickmc-ThinkPad-T420:~/tmp$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Drivers]
NetezzaSQL = Installed

[NetezzaSQL]
Description = Netezza ODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
FileUsage = 1
APILevel = 1
ConnectFunctions = YYN
DriverODBCVer = 03.50
UnicodeTranslationOption = utf8
CharacterTranslationOption = all
PreFetch = 256
Socket = 8192
LogPath = /tmp
DebugLogging = false

[ODBC]
Trace = No
```

and my /etc/odbc.ini:

```
;
;  odbc.ini
;
[ODBC Data Sources]
NZSQL_SERVER = NetezzaSQL


[NZSQL_SERVER]
Driver                = /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
Description           = NetezzaSQL ODBC
Servername            = db.mynetwork.net
Port                  = 5480
Database              = db_1
Username              = db_user
Password              = db_pass
ReadOnly              = false
ShowSystemTables      = true
LegacySQLTables       = false
LoginTimeout          = 0
QueryTimeout          = 0
DateFormat            = 1
NumericAsChar         = false
SQLBitOneZero         = false
StripCRLF             = false
securityLevel         = preferredUnSecured
caCertFile            =
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `odbc.ini` file, try changing this line:

```
Driver                = /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
```

to this:

```
Driver                = NetezzaSQL
```

and see if that helps.

*UPDATE:*

I've never used `iodbctest` but a quick search indicates you may be specifying things incorrectly.  Here's a snippet from [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/iodbctest.1.html) man page:

```
$ iodbctest
OpenLink ODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): ?

DSN                              | Driver
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ora9                             | OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver
mysql                            | OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver
mysqllite                        | OpenLink Lite for MySQL
myodbc                           | MyODBC Driver
pgsql                            | OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver
tds                              | OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): DSN=ora9;PWD=tiger
Driver: 05.20.0316 OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver (oplodbc.so)

SQL>
```

Looks like you need to specify the **connect string**, not just the DSN.

If that doesn't work, you should try these:

- `ls -l /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so` to check the driver
- Make sure you don't have a `~/.odbc.ini` file or the `ODBCINI` var set
- Try enabling DebugLogging (`odbcinst.ini`) and Trace / TraceFile (`odbc.ini`)

Comment: Nope, no change

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be a library difference between the two machines.

Make sure you have only one ODBC driver manager (iODBC is what you've pictured; UnixODBC may also be installed), at least in the active LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

If that doesn't clear things up, then enabling ODBC Tracing and/or Driver Debug Logging is likely to bring more information to light.

It currently appears that the driver is returning an error in a different codepage than the driver manager expects, and so you get the several "unknown character" glyphs.  We do see an error number -- 33 -- which corresponds to "Server and/or port attributes are empty" though they are set in the DSN, which suggests other possible environmental issues (Is $ODBCINI set? Does it point to /etc/odbc.ini?)....

If in doubt, perhaps take a look at [the official Netezza docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.netezza.use.doc/topics/configuring_nzodbc_linuxfile.html)!